# Cannot import / add native Kotlin Module in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

### Problem

I am trying to create my own native module, but React Native can't load it. I always get this error when trying to start the app with `npx react-native start`:

> /home/somedude/Development/my-app/android/app/src/main/java/com/coolapp/MainApplication.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
> packages.add(new GLBPackage());
> ^
> symbol: class GLBPackage

### What I did

I followed the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android?android-language=kotlin) to a point to create that module. This is from my *MainApplication.java*:

```
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ReactViroPackage(ReactViroPackage.ViroPlatform.valueOf("AR")));
      packages.add(new GLBPackage());

      return packages;
    }
```

I also created an *GLBPackage.kt*:

```
class GLBPackage : ReactPackage {

    override fun createViewManagers(
        reactContext: ReactApplicationContext
    ): MutableList<ViewManager<View, ReactShadowNode<*>>> = mutableListOf()

    override fun createNativeModules(
        reactContext: ReactApplicationContext
    ): MutableList<NativeModule> = listOf(GLBModule(reactContext)).toMutableList()
}
```

and a *GLBModule.kt*:

```
class GLBModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return "GLBModule"
    }

    @ReactMethod
    fun loadModel(path: String) {
        Log.d("GLBModule", "Loading $path")
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error? Android Studio also says everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar error when trying to load the CalendarModule provided in the ReactNative docs using Kotlin.

What worked for me:
I added the kotlin-android plugin the app level build.gradle file like so:

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`

And, the androidx.core and kotlin implementations under the implementation section like so:

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:$'`
`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"`

Similarly, I also added the following configs in the project level build.gradle file in the dependencies section, like so:

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

Source: [React Native Project with Kotlin and Swift](https://anilsisodiya.medium.com/react-native-project-with-kotlin-and-swift-4169083ee847)

Comment: I get this error when trying to do this: _> Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler._ Does this mean I  have to enter a specific Kotlin version?

Comment: My bad, the variable is named kotlinVersion for me. Works now, great and thanks.